# Post request with js and jsp in MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/list/a")
public String showFormForAdd(@RequestParam(value="monthParam") String month,Model model) {
    
    System.out.println(month);
    model.addAttribute("daysMod",month);
    
    return "two";
}
```

Why when I send a post request from jsp №1,controller accept arguments `monthParam` and open new jsp-page №2.

```
<form action="/arakaru/customer/list/a" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="monthParam" value="Janu">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Customer"/> 
</form>
```

but when I do the same with js(sending a post request with the argument `monthParam`),controller accept only the argument,but it doesn't open new jsp page.Are there any options for opening a new jsp page by getting an argument from js?

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
//console.log(cityName);

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/arakaru/customer/list/a";
var params = "monthParam="+cityName;
http.open('POST', url, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);
```

[jsp page №2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk6es.png)(only works when post come from jsp№1)

Comment: you can't open jsp pages directly via clientside JS, this needs to happen in backend

Comment: @FelixSchildmann but I am trying to open a new jsp in the controller

Comment: Ofcourse it won't. JavaScript is handled in the background and so it the result. So you receive the rendered page as the result of your javascript call. You will need to handle that in your javascript handler. Another thing, please include the code in your post, don't let people click 4 links to get the full overview of your sample. Also use proper code tags to post code instead of images (due to resizing those are generally unreadable).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/arakaru/customer/list/a?monthParam="+cityName
```

Your controller is expecting a request parameter (@RequestParam) in query String.

Comment: I successfully get a parameter with the post method,i don't think that's the problem

Comment: @Слава just try once